# Is there any way to show the dependency trees for pip packages?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a project with multiple package dependencies, the main requirements being listed in `requirements.txt`. When I call `pip freeze` it prints the currently installed packages as plain list. I would prefer to also get their dependency relationships, something like this:

```
Flask==0.9
    Jinja2==2.7
    Werkzeug==0.8.3

Jinja2==2.7

Werkzeug==0.8.3

Flask-Admin==1.0.6
    Flask==0.9
    Jinja2==2.7
    Werkzeug==0.8.3
```

The goal is to detect the dependencies of each specific package:

```
Werkzeug==0.8.3
    Flask==0.9
    Flask-Admin==1.0.6
```

And insert these into my current `requirements.txt`. For example, for this input:

```
Flask==0.9
Flask-Admin==1.0.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
```

I would like to get:

```
Flask==0.9
    Jinja2==2.7
Flask-Admin==1.0.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
```

Is there any way show the dependencies of installed pip packages?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

You should take a look at [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipdeptree):

```
$ pip install pipdeptree
$ pipdeptree -fl
Warning!!! Cyclic dependencies found:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
xlwt==0.7.5
ruamel.ext.rtf==0.1.1
xlrd==0.9.3
openpyxl==2.0.4
  - jdcal==1.0
pymongo==2.7.1
reportlab==3.1.8
  - Pillow==2.5.1
  - pip
  - setuptools
```

It doesn't generate a `requirements.txt` file as you indicated directly. However the source (255 lines of python code) should be relatively easy to modify to your needs, or alternatively you can (as @MERose indicated is in the pipdeptree 0.3 README ) out use:

```
pipdeptree --freeze  --warn silence | grep -P '^[\w0-9\-=.]+' > requirements.txt
```

The 0.5 version of `pipdeptree` also allows JSON output with the `--json` option, that is more easily machine parseble, at the expense of being less readable.

Comment: According to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipdeptree/0.3, `pipdeptree | grep -P '^\w+'` prints a requirements.txt.

Comment: @MERose Thanks for pointing that out. I must have still been using version 0.2 when I wrote this.

Comment: It is not working for `bokeh` :( This package have specific organization of requirements so pip does not show them, but conda does.

Comment: It can now directly generate a requirements.txt directly using the --freeze flag

Comment: As of 2022, project is no longer maintained and not compatible with newer pip and py311.

Comment: @sorin, I see a 2024 release on pypi...

Answer (score 11):

## Warning: py2 only / abandonware

[`yolk`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk/0.4.3) can display dependencies for packages, provided that they

- were installed via `setuptools`
- came with metadata that includes dependency information

  ```
  $ yolk -d Theano
  Theano 0.6.0rc3
    scipy>=0.7.2
    numpy>=1.5.0
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure if there can be a full solution - the problem is that dependency information doesn't always exist (for example for packages installed via `distutils`, which does not support package metadata)

Comment: yolk doesn't have py3k support as of the time of writing.

Comment: Someone already did the port: https://pypi.org/project/yolk3k/

Answer (score 10):

You can do it by installing `pipdeptree` package.

Open command prompt in your project folder. If you are using any virtual environment, then switch to that virtual environment.

Install `pipdeptree` package using pip

```
pip install pipdeptree
pipdeptree -fl
```

This package will list all the dependencies of your project.

For more [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I realize that many years has passed since this question was asked, but it showed up in my searches so I thought I'd share some knowledge.

The `pip-tools` package contains a tool called `pip-compile` that seems to also solve the original poster's problem.

`pip-compile` takes an input file, which can be setup.py, setup.cfg, pyproject.toml, or requirements.in. The input file is what you write by hand and contains the "direct" dependencies. It may not specify exact dependency versions, but may use version ranges (nor no constraints at all). The tool outputs a new rquirements.txt file with all the indirect dependencies added and also pins down the dependencies to exact versions.

If you run the `pip-compile` tool again after updating the source file, it will add or remove dependencies from the output file if needed. You can also choose to upgrade a specific dependency by adding a flag.

So while `pip-compile` does not show you the dependency tree itself, it helps you with collecting all the leafs of the dependency tree (which I assume was what the original poster wanted to do in the end).

Read more here: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/

Answer (score 0):

## Use pip-compile command to freeze requirements.in file

Pip-tools v6.14.0 seems to have pip-compile command to generate `requirements.txt` file with annotate by default. I see you just intend to freeze your installed package from virtualenv, but a better way is to have a `setup.py` or `requirements.in` file where you write your installed packages with the version.

Output will be similar to below:

```
# requirements.txt
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with Python 3.7
# by the following command:
#
#    pip-compile --no-emit-index-url --output-file requirements.txt setup.py
#
my-private-package==2.3.0
    # via my-repo (setup.py)
alembic==1.7.4
    # via my-private-package-dep
amqp==2.6.1
    # via kombu
```

You can also use `--no-annotate` arg to turn off dependencies annotation.