# How to analyze dependency tree for conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Is there a tool for analyzing Conda dependencies as we do have in Maven?

ie: In Java projects (maven based) you say `mvn dependency:tree` and it shows all the dependencies (along with transitive dependencies) in a readable tree format.

I was wondering if we have something in python based project to analyze Conda dependencies.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are just looking for packages you can use `pip freeze` to list the currently installed packages and their respective versions. Is that along the lines of what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to see what all dependencies are in my application along with their transitive dependencies. The core idea is to prune unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: There is the `conda install/remove --prune package_name` command that walks the tree and prunes unnecessary packages. But I'm not aware of a way to visualize that.

Answer (score 26):

Check out [conda-tree](https://github.com/rvalieris/conda-tree).

Usage (based on the [conda-tree](https://github.com/rvalieris/conda-tree) webpage):

```
# version
$ conda-tree --version
conda-tree 0.0.4

# packages that no other package depends on
$ conda-tree leaves
['samtools','bcftools',...]

# dependencies of a specific package
$ conda-tree depends samtools
['curl', 'xz', 'libgcc', 'zlib']

# which packages depend on a specific package
$ conda-tree whoneeds xz
['samtools', 'bcftools', 'htslib', 'python']

# dependency cycles
$ conda-tree cycles
pip -> python -> pip
pip -> wheel -> python -> pip

# query a different conda prefix/env
$ conda-tree -p /conda/envs/trinity leaves
['trinity']

# query by name
$ conda-tree -n trinity leaves
['trinity']
```

For dependencies installed with `pip`, check out [`pipdeptree`](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree). It will return a dependency tree of the packages (installed with `pip`. See the [documentation](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree#limitations--alternatives))

try:

```
pipdeptree
```

Or if you are looking for the *leaves* only

```
pipdeptree --freeze  --warn silence | grep -P '^[\w0-9\-=.]+'
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903067/6715335) answer.

Comment: When I run `./conda-tree.py leaves`, I get `bash: ./conda-tree.py: No such file or directory`, so that command obviously doesn't as is. Where is `conda-tree.py` located?

Comment: OK. I just changed the commands. It seems that the README is outdated. Thanks @HelloGoodbye

Comment: It seems that `conda-tree` fails to list any packages installed with `pip`; at least on my system.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye [`pipdeptree`](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) works for packages installed with `pip`

Comment: That is correct. Pipdeptree doesnnot work for Conda

Comment: @Lovey I just updated the answer. See also https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree#limitations--alternatives

Comment: Thanks, let me check.

Comment: is there any tools like `pipdeptree` in the `conda` repo (i couldn't find conda tree in the `conda search`)?

Comment: @trevor-boyd-smith you have to install the packages [conda-tree](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/conda-tree), [pipdeptree](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pipdeptree) from [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/).

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge conda-tree` to install

Comment: `conda-tree whoneeds <package> --tree --full` to see deeper-level dependency relationships. Omitting `--tree` results in a list of just the packages that _immediately_ depend on `<package>`, not accounting for transitive dependencies.