# Is there a way to update a package and, recursively, all the packages it uses?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have created a package for internal use. In my setup file I have something like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='myutils',
    version='0.3',
    description='Set of utils for these projects',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'requests',
        'arrow',
        'slackclient'
    ]
)
```

It works well and it installs all the packages in `install_requires` smoothly.

However, from time to time some of these packages may need an update, so I expected `pip install --upgrade myutils` to update the packages in `install_requires`, while it does not.

Is there a way to do some kind of `pip install --upgrade --recursive myutils` or similar, so that the *inner* packages are installed as well? The only workaround I can think of is to define a minimum package version in the form of `package>=that_version.X.y.z`, but [it does not seem to be the most recommended way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40000206/1983854).

Comment: I hope someone will show a better solution. Solutions, that I know, are just shell scripts building the necessary pip command. See for example the pipdeptree package mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903067/5378816

Comment: if your package requires a particular version of a required package specify the version number, or just specify the latest version that you know. The links does not tell the recommended way only the diff between `install_requires` and `requirements.txt`

Comment: thanks, @rioV8. Going through the other question I could see references to not pinning a version and I somehow got the impression that specifying versions there is not its main purpose. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pip somewhat recently (a few years ago now that I check) changed the default strategy for `--upgrade` -- it used to upgrade the package and any transitive packages but changed to only upgrading the package

fortunately, a new option was added which controls this behaviour: `--upgrade-strategy`

to restore the old "upgrade everything" approach, you can use `pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy=eager PKG`  (the default strategy is `only-if-needed`)

Answer (score 1):

you can force an upgrade of all installed packages with the following command line on Unix like OS

```
pip freeze | sed -r -e 's/([^=]+)==.*/\1/' | xargs pip install --upgrade
```