# ERROR: pyzmq has an invalid wheel, multiple .dist-info directories found: libsodium-1.0.17.dist-info, pyzmq-18.1.0.dist-info

Tags: python, github, pyzmq

I have a problem cloning a project from GitHub. The error occurs when I try to install the requirements.txt file:

> ERROR: pyzmq has an invalid wheel, multiple .dist-info directories
> found: libsodium-1.0.17.dist-info, pyzmq-18.1.0.dist-info

I tried the below options but nothing worked. Any idea how can I solve the problem?

> pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

> pip install --no-binary=:all: pyzmq==18.1.0

> pip install wheel

I also opened the requirements.txt file and removed this package, but other packages didn't install correctly!

Comment: Did you fix this? Which repo is the requirement.txt located in? It might help to know which packages are being installed.

Comment: No it is not fixed yet. the repo address is repo address is: https://github.com/ChrisFugl/Intrusing-Detection-System-Attack

Comment: Did you try asking on the issue tracker for that repository?

Comment: What OS and version of Python are you using? I tried installing the requirements on Windows 10 with Python 3.7 and 3.8 and had issues with `scipy==1.3.1` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)). I did not get the same error message as you.

Comment: the version of python is 3.8.3 and I am working on windows 64. which spicy version works?

Comment: Try downloading [SciPy v.1.3.2.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.3.2) That's the first version where support for Python 3.8 was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Solution based on specific repo mentioned by OP:**

I was able to install the requirements.txt in this [repo](https://github.com/ChrisFugl/Intrusing-Detection-System-Attack) using the following steps. Tested on Windows 10 and Python 3.7.

1. Download the scipy v1.3.1 wheel file from [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.3.1). Only Python 3.5-3.7 are supported, so pick the right version (cp35-cp37). Also pick the right OS and 32/64-bits version.
2. Run `pip install scipy-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` (for example) from the folder where the .whl file is.
3. In requirements.txt: change `tensorflow==2.0.0b0` to `tensorflow==2.0.0`
4. In requirements.txt: change `torch==1.3.0` to `torch==1.9.0`
5. Run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

**Original Answer:**

I personally saw the `pyzmq has an invalid wheel` error while installing `tensorflow==2.7.0` with `tfx==1.3.3`. According to the [tfx repo](https://pypi.org/project/tfx/), these versions are not compatible, and result in a dependency conflict. You might have two similar dependencies that are doing the same.

I solved this in 3 ways:

1. Specify compatible versions. In my case, switching to `tensorflow==2.6.0` worked.
2. Search for and remove redundant dependencies. In my case, `tensorflow` is already included with `tfx`. Removing it fixed the problem (actually there was another bug, but that's off-topic).
3. Add a specific version of `pyzmq` to your requirements.txt to force the resolution. I used the [latest version](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/) (`pyzmq==22.3.0`), which also fixed the issue.

To help debug the problem, you can view the pip dependency tree using [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903067/5752730).

Comment: For python version 3.8.3 which spicy version should I use? I am working on Window 64.